# How To Convert List of List To LIST Using robot Framework Keywords

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to convert `list of list` to LIST using `robot framework` keywords.Output of my script in log file was like this :

```
@{ListA} = [ [a, b] | [c, d, e] | f | g]
```

I wanted to flatten this list as

```
 [ a , b , c , d , e , f , g]
```

How to convert this?

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In the code in your question you aren't creating a list. More accurately, you're creating a list with one element,which is a string that looks like `"[ (a,b), ...]"`. Do you have an actual list-of-lists, or do you literally want to transform this string to a list of lists, and then flatten it out?

Comment: @BryanOakley , I meant to say that  output of my script was as: 
@{ListA} = [ [a, b] | [c, d, e] | f | g]

I wanted to flatten this list as  [ a | b | c | d | e | f | g]

Comment: That is even less precise of an answer. The pipes isn't valid python syntax _or_ robot syntax.

Comment: what are "a", "b", etc? Are they supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions are quite powerful, and can be used with the Evaluate keyword. Here you can force each item to be a list by checking to see if it already is - the "(sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])" part. Once you have a list of lists, you can flatten that with the nesting ability of a list comprehension.

Some folks frown upon type-checking in Python, but one of the struggles is that strings and lists can be mistaken. Here a direct type-check is used. There are other approaches to check if an object is a list and you can modify this as needed.

```
List of lists and Other Items
    @{InnerA}    Create List    a    b
    @{InnerB}    Create List    c    d    e
    @{ListA}    Create List    ${InnerA}    ${InnerB}    f    g
    ${flat}    Evaluate    [item for sublist in $ListA for item in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])]
    Log List    ${flat}
```

_

```
INFO : @{InnerA} = [ a | b ]
INFO : @{InnerB} = [ c | d | e ]
INFO : @{ListA} = [ [u'a', u'b'] | [u'c', u'd', u'e'] | f | g ]
INFO : ${flat} = [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g']
INFO : 
List length is 7 and it contains following items:
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
4: e
5: f
6: g
```